# JQuery Template Class with background image not loading when site is in an iFrame (MVC4)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, internet-explorer-9, jquery-templates

#### Greetings all, I have a very unique (it seems) issue that none of us here can seem to wrap our heads around.  Let me give you the context and then I'll provide some code.

### CONTEXT:

We have a site, we'll call it 'TheLegacy'.  'TheLegacy' is being phased out.  We are creating a site , let's call it 'TheFuture'.  'TheFuture' is an upgraded version of 'TheLegacy'.  We are using MVC4 to do the work with some jquery and knockout behind the scenes.  'TheFuture' is being rolled out in phases and, until it is complete, will host 'TheLegacy' inside an iFrame inside of 'TheFuture'.  This is so users can access certain functions/pages they need that haven't been built yet in 'TheFuture'.

### ISSUE:

All is well except for one, severly frustrating issue.  There is an assignments page in 'TheLegacy' that is a grid of data.  This grid is built with an html table using a JQuery template.  Inside of each row, there is a "" tag that has a class.  This class has two things, css background and css hand properties.  There is also jquery functionality linked to this class.  The class is called 'chevronArrow'.  When the user hovers or clicks the div with 'chevronArrow' it should jquery addClass 'chevronArrowActive' and when the user clicks another one or 'unhovers' it should revert to 'chevronArrowInactive'.

Let me specify that everything above works perfectly fine.  The only problem is that when 'TheLegacy' is viewed inside of 'TheFuture's iFrame, the image for the 'chevronArrowActive' and 'chevronArrowInactive' refuse to show.  To top it off, this is only an issue in IE, Chrome works fine.  'TheLegacy' also works perfectly fine when viewed by itself (outside of 'TheFuture' iFrame) in IE or Chrome.

### ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS:

-We tried injecting css on 'TheFuture' iframe load.  No dice.

-We tried appending direct styles to the elements, body, and head of 'TheLegacy' on 'TheFuture' iframe load. No dice.

-We tried taking the direct styles and manually placing it at the bottom of the body in 'TheLegacy'.  This worked, but isn't a practical solution.

### WHAT WE NEED:

We need to understand why this is happening or if anyone has run into something similar or has any concept of why this occurs.

### CODE:

This code is inside of the .htm file used for the jquery template:

#### class portion:

```
.chevronArrowInactive
{
    background:url('Images/chevron_arrow_inactive.png') no-repeat left center;
    cursor:hand;
}

.chevronArrowActive
{
    background:url('Images/chevron_arrow_active.png') no-repeat left center;
    cursor:hand;
}
```

#### html portion:

```
<a href="" title="Click to view list of producer code(s)" class="jqrAgencyProducerCount"><div style="width:100%;height:20px" class="chevronArrowInactive chevronArrow"></div></a>
```

Comment: Is 'The Future' being accessed via SSL?

Comment: No, everything is running localhost right now on http

Comment: We are currently going with the approach to add both the .chevronArrowActive & .chevronArrowInactive classes to a style tag at the end of the body in 'TheLegacy', for that assignments page.  This is allowing it to work in all browsers and whether it is standing alone or inside of 'TheFutre'.  Certainly not the most desireable resolution.